# How to add variable in middleman html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

I have some .yml files that may be dynamic. So I wanted to add this kind of code on my html:

```
<h3><%=data.fitness_programs["#{f.filename}"].en.title%></h3>
```

Looks line the rails `"#{var_in_here}"` is not possible here.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, as this was a loop of filenames I did not realize I had an error in one of these. The code above does work :)